# Error al Insertar datos adicionales en tabla pivot usando sync

Tags: php, laravel-8, pivot

Expongo este tema ya tratado en diferentes hilos que en mi caso me genera un error que no consigo solucionar.

Tengo una relación de muchos a muchos con los modelos **Client** y **Factor**. Lo que quiero hacer es almacenar en la tabla pivote **client_factor** dos campos extra, aparte de los id de las dos tablas relacionadas (**factor_id, client_id**), que serán **pointsfactor** (puntos asignados) y **gender** (género).

**Modelo Client**

```
public function clientsFactors()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Factor::class, 'client_factor')->withPivot('pointsfactor', 'gender');
}
```

**Modelo Factor**

```
public function factorsClients()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class, 'client_factor')->withPivot('pointsfactor', 'gender');
}
```

**Migración Tabla Pivote client_factor**

```
public function up()
{
 Schema::create(
  'client_factor', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->foreignId('factor_id')->constrained('factors')->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->foreignId('client_id')->constrained('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->integer('pointsfactor')->default(0);
      $table->string('gender')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
     }
 );
}
```

Los datos a insertar en la tabla pivot los recojo de un formulario que devuelve 3 arrays (**factor_id[], pointsfactor[], gender[]**).

**Array Factor_id**

```
array:15 [▼
0 => "1"
1 => "2"
2 => "3"
3 => "4"
4 => "5"
5 => "6"
6 => "7"
7 => "8"
8 => "9"
9 => "10"
10 => "11"
11 => "12"
12 => "13"
13 => "14"
14 => "15"
]
```

**Array Poinsfactor**

```
array:15 [▼
0 => "5"
1 => "5"
2 => "15"
3 => "5"
4 => "25"
5 => "5"
6 => "5"
7 => "10"
8 => "5"
9 => "8"
10 => "5"
11 => "5"
12 => "5"
13 => "25"
14 => "5"
]
```

**Array Gender**

```
array:15 [▼
0 => "NEUTRO"
1 => "NEUTRO"
2 => "FEMENINO"
3 => "MASCULINO"
4 => "MASCULINO"
5 => "NEUTRO"
6 => "NEUTRO"
7 => "MASCULINO"
8 => "NEUTRO"
9 => "FEMENINO"
10 => "FEMENINO"
11 => "FEMENINO"
12 => "NEUTRO"
13 => "NEUTRO"
14 => "NEUTRO"
]
```

Para guardar los datos en la tabla pivot, le paso al método **sync** el array con las id de los factores y los arrays con los datos de las columnas adicionales.

```
$factores = $request->factor_id;
$puntos = $request->pointsfactor;
$genero = $request->gender;

$client->clientsFactors()->sync(
  [
     $factores => [
       'pointsfactor' => implode(",", $puntos),
       'gender' => implode(",", $genero)
     ]

  ]
);
```

Pero me genera siguiente error: **Mensaje de error:Illegal offset type**

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?, ¿Cómo tendría que realizar la inserción de los campos adicionales en la table pivot?.

Gracias...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que esta mal es que es la variable $factores tienes un array, y no un valor puedes organizar tu arreglo para que te queda algo asi:

```
$factores = [
  1 => ['pointsfactor' => 5, 'gender' => "NEUTRO"],
  2 => ['pointsfactor' => 5, 'gender' => "NEUTRO"],
  3 => ['pointsfactor' => 5, 'gender' => "FEMENINO"],
   ...
]
```

y una vez con el arreglo organizado puedes hacer:

```
$client->clientsFactors()->sync($factores);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración Juan David, me ha sido de gran ayuda. Ya he conseguido syncronizar los datos en la tabla pivot.